# Show that $\operatorname E\left[\|X\|^n\right]<\infty$ implies that the characteristic function of $X$ is $n$-times differentiable

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-pde

If $X$ is a real-valued random variable with characteristic function $\varphi_X$, then we know that $\operatorname E\left[|X|^n\right]<\infty$ implies that $\varphi_X$ is $n$-times continuously differentiable with derivative $$\varphi_X^{(k)}=\operatorname E\left[({\rm i}X)^ke^{{\rm i}tX}\right]\tag1$$ for all $k=0,\ldots,n$.

> Are we able to generalize this result to random variables $Y$ with values in a Banach (or Hilbert) space $E$?

In this case, the characteristic function is given by $$\varphi_Y(x')=\operatorname E\left[e^{{\rm i}\langle Y,\:x'\rangle}\right]\;\;\;\text{for all }x'\in E'.$$

Comment: I think a generalization is possible using the exact same proof as the real case. All that was needed in the proof is the fundamental theorem of calculus in the form $$f(x + h) - f(x) = \int_{0}^1Df(x + th)h\,dt$$ and DCT. This FTC holds for any $R^n$ valued $f$ defined on a Banach space; to prove it apply the usual FTC to $\phi(t) = f(x + th)$, $t \in [0, 1]$.

Comment: @JoseAvilez Yes, sorry.